# Multilanguage development

Tags: c#, java, makefile, multilingual

I would like to develop an application with two languages.
Actually, the goal is to generate two differents application, one with a language (Java), the other on in another language (C#).

I would like to use makefiles to help me generate one application or the other one, thanks to targets definition.

I don't know where to begin.
Have you ever try to develop like this ?
Is it possible to use one makefile to call java compiler or c# compiler using different targets ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which language will you use to code your application?

Comment: Ant with dot net extensions (http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/dotnet/) might be easier than make.

Comment: Are you saying you want to generate the same application in two different languages - and somehow automate the production of one from the other?  So effectively you want to automate the translation from Java to C# or vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use a make file to compile (and link) source files for different languages. There's no limitation. All you need is a compiler (linker) that can be called by a shell / from a command line.

Alternatives: ant can do both Java and C#. If you don't need to build both applications with a single build file, you still can use separate files and write a batch/shell script to call both builders.

Comment: +1 for separate build files.  Or you could arrange `make` that runs `ant` or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, this is my idea : call coorect compiler and linker following the correct target chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to override a Makefile variable to point to either javac or the .NET compiler.

You will, however, most likely not benefit from this as it is very hard to write a program that is valid in both languages.

You may want to look into http://www.ikvm.net/ which provides a Java emulation environment under .NET, so if you have a Java program it can run under .NET.

Comment: thanks for you answer.
ikvm looks great but it transform source files, and here i must develop both languages.

Comment: I would suggest you describe your actual scenario in more detail in your question then.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the Fantom project, which claims to do that, but I have strong doubts regarding cross-platform support (how can you abstract all side-effects of all APIs?).

But I don't know the project, maybe they do a fine job.

http://fantom.org/

Answer (score 0):

my idea is pretty dumb but i guess you could try this:
step 1: make a bat file
step 2: make the 2 script files
step 3: make it so it executes both of them!

```
@echo off
start yourfile.script
start yourfile.script
```

this idea is gonna fail